Exclude specific folder from Fortifty SAST Scan
I have a CI pipeline that runs Fortify SAST Scan. I managed to successfully get the Fortify report. However, Fortify scan flagged issues from their own folder (I have fortify-scripts folder in my project repo). The scan also flagged unit tests (my unit test files have spec.ts).
Below the snippet of my yml file:-
 - task: FortifyScanCentralSAST@7
        displayName: 'Run SAST Scan'
        inputs:
          scanExclusions: 'fortify-scripts,**/*.spec.ts'
          scanCentralCtrlUrl: '$(sast-controller-url)'
          scanCentralClientToken: '$(sast-client-token)'
          sscUrl: '$(ssc-url)'

The scanExclusions doesnt work as it still pick up issues from the files/folder that I dont it to scan. Now, how do I go around this?

As mentioned in my answer below, the 'filter' option on the FortifyScanCentralSAST@7 task can be used to specify which folder or file need to scan. It is not to exclude the specified folder or file. @amh_300

There is not an option named 'scanExclusions' on the FortifyScanCentralSAST@7 task. It is an invalid and unavailable option on the task. That should be why it does not work.
On the FortifyScanCentralSAST@7 task, there is an available option 'filter' (Filter file) that can allow you to specify the particular folder or file to be scanned.

So, you can try to configure the task like as below.
steps:
- task: FortifyScanCentralSAST@7
  displayName: 'Run SAST Scan'
  inputs:
    scanCentralCtrlUrl: '$(sast-controller-url)'
    scanCentralClientToken: '$(sast-client-token)'
    sscUrl: '$(ssc-url)'
    buildTool: gradle
    filter: path/to/particular/folder/or/file



Thanks for your answer. I tried this one, but the scan report still go through the folder that I specified in the 'filter'. I dont think 'filter' option is the correct one for file exclusion selection

@amh_300, The 'filter' option is to specify which folder or file need to scan, not exclude the specified one.
